# Android: Async Task | Do in background freezes up UI?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am having an issue and have looked all over the place (youtube, dev sites) for a solution and am unable to find one.

The UI in my application is hanging when the volley connection is started, I added it to an AsyncTask overriding DoInBackground method but it still hangs.

The code I have handling the connection through volley is:

```
public class DoInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        //Adding cameras from server using volley...
        String url = "FullUrlHere";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

        JsonArrayRequest jArrayReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                //Response received
                try {
                    int sizeOfArray = response.getInt(0);
                    String element = response.getString(1);

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Size: " + sizeOfArray, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Now we have the size of array, now to cycle through them
                    for (int i = 1; i < sizeOfArray + 1; i++) {
                        //Cycle through
                        String nextAddress = response.getString(i);
                        //Put into our array
                        cameraAddresses.add(nextAddress);
                    }

                    for (String address : cameraAddresses) {
                        String camAddress = address;
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latitudeValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //Start reverse geo coding. (Turning address into coordinates.)
                        Geocoder camLocationGeocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                        List<Address> addresses;
                        addresses = camLocationGeocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
                        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                            double latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                            double longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
                            //Add markers.
                            Marker camera = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Possible Speed Camera.").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.camera_placemarker)));
                            cameraList.add(camera);
                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Error caught.
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Error
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jArrayReq);
        return null;
    }
}


private void addLocations() {
    //Below code to be performed on BG thread

    for (Marker camera : cameraList) {
        camera.remove(); //Remove camera, we will re-add them in a while.
    }
    cameraList.clear(); //Remove all cameras from arrayList

    //Execute Task
    new DoInBackground().execute();
}
```

Comment: I dont no what it is freezing but i know one thing, that doInBackground() cannot add marker to the map since map is defined in UI Thread and you are trying to add a marker to it from different Thread. dont leave the catch() empty, print what the exception..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to override `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate`?

AsyncTask have 4 methods:

- `onPreExecute()` -> runs in main thread before `doInBacground()` will be called
- `doInBackground(Object[] params)` -> runs in background and cannot interact with UI
- `onProgressUpdate(Object[] values)` -> runs in main thread while you call the method `publishProgress(Object... values)` in `doInBackground`
- `onPostExecute(Object result)` -> runs in main thread when `doInBackground` ends the task

Im not sure if the methods that you are using to create the cameras must be executed in the main thread, but if youd didn't solve the problem yet, you can try to instance the new cameras into the `onProgressUpdate` and call `publishProgress` from `doInBackground` each time that you have the data to create a camera.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

> Do in background freezes up UI?

`doInBackground` as name indicates is running on seapare, no UI thread. It will not block the UI thread (it may however cause i.e. heavy load that would affect the UI thread as well, but that other story).

Comment: But you have not answered question. :/
I know it is not supposed to block UI thread but it is and I don't know why.

Comment: I answered `Do in background freezes up UI?` question. Also "freezes" means nothing specific here and is too generic. How do you know it is not your camera removal loop that causes the troubles? Did you profile or checked in any other way?

Comment: I will add the camera removal loop to the doInBackground and see, one sec. I should note during testing there is only 2 in the loop so should not freeze up UI. But let me see.

Comment: doInBackground cannot touch UI, so you most likely end up crashing

Comment: Ahhh, it did crash. But only when it had a camera to move. I am testing on launch and removal loop will not run as nothing to remove.